# How do I sort a zipped list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, zip

What's the Pythonic way to sort a zipped list?

code :

```
names = list('datx')
vals  = reversed(list(xrange(len(names))))
zipped = zip(names, vals)

print zipped
```

The code above prints **[('d', 3), ('a', 2), ('t', 1), ('x', 0)]**

I want to sort **zipped** by the values. So ideally it would end up looking like this **[('x', 0), ('t', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 3)]**.

Comment: The first two answers show off a pet peeve of mine about Python: the presence of both `sorted` and `sort`.

Comment: There's good reason for both: `.sort()` sorts a list in-place.  And `sorted` works on any iterator, but needs to use additional storage to accomplish the task.

Comment: @JasonFruit: If you don't know the difference, I highly recommend you find out.

Comment: @Matt Joiner, Ned Batchelder: I know the difference; I think I've not made myself clear.  What bugs me is that sort() is a method, and sorted is a built-in function.  It doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: @JasonFruit (I know this is from a while back), but `sorted` is consistent with other special python syntax, including `in`, `len`, and `reversed`, which depend upon the `__contains__`, `__len__`, and `__getitem__` + `__len__` respectively (I think `sorted` needs `__getitem__` and `__len__` but I'm not sure). In many ways, it's also similar to the syntax for `[]` which is based on `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, or `()` which initializes `__call__`. They're builtin functions that translate special internal functions into clear external syntax.

Comment: @JeffTratner, it makes more sense in that context.  Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
sorted(zipped, key = lambda t: t[1])
```

Answer (score 83):

Quite simple:

```
sorted(zipped, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: This is the solution for Python 3

Answer (score 10):

```
import operator
sorted(zipped, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

If you want it a little bit more faster, do `ig = operator.itemgetter(1)` and use `ig` as key function.

Answer (score 5):

In your case you don't need to sort at all because you just want an enumerated reversed list of your `names`:

```
>>> list(enumerate(names[::-1]))      # reverse by slicing
[(0, 'x'), (1, 't'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'd')]

>>> list(enumerate(reversed(names)))  # but reversed is also possible
[(0, 'x'), (1, 't'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'd')]
```

---

But if you need to sort it then you should use `sorted` (as provided by @utdemir or @Ulrich Dangel) because it will work on Python2 (`zip` and `itertools.zip`) and Python3 (`zip`) and won't fail with an `AttributeError` like `.sort(...)` (which only works on Python2 `zip` because there `zip` returns a `list`):

```
>>> # Fails with Python 3's zip:
>>> zipped = zip(names, vals)
>>> zipped.sort(lambda x: x[1])
AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort'

>>> # Fails with Python 2's itertools izip:
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> zipped = izip(names, vals)
>>> zipped.sort(lambda x: x[1])
AttributeError: 'itertools.izip' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

But `sorted` does work in each case:

```
>>> zipped = izip(names, vals)
>>> sorted(zipped, key=lambda x: x[1])
[('x', 0), ('t', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 3)]

>>> zipped = zip(names, vals)  # python 3
>>> sorted(zipped, key=lambda x: x[1])
[('x', 0), ('t', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simpler and more efficient to zip them in order in the first place (if you can). Given your example it's pretty easy:

```
>>> names = 'datx'
>>> zip(reversed(names), xrange(len(names)))
<<< [('x', 0), ('t', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort feature importance in a classifier (dtc=decision_tree):

```
for name, importance in sorted(zip(X_train.columns, 
                dtc.feature_importances_),key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(name, importance)
```