# Sorting a zipped object in python 3

Tags: python, sorting

I've a `zip` object and I want to sort it(based on a specific key).

I've already seen [How do I sort a zipped list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142227/how-do-i-sort-a-zipped-list-in-python) but the accepted answer does not work in python 3.6 anymore.

For example

```
In [6]: a = [3,9,2,24,1,6]

In [7]: b = ['a','b','c','d','e']

In [8]: c = zip(a,b)

In [9]: c
Out[9]: <zip at 0x108f59ac8>

In [11]: type(c)
Out[11]: zip

In [12]: c.sort()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a21727fa8976> in <module>()
----> 1 c.sort()

AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort'

# Wanted this to be sorted by the first element
In [13]: for l,r in c: print(l,r)
3 a
9 b
2 c
24 d
1 e
```

In other words how do I make the zip iteration order conform to the sorting order. 
I'm aware that converting a zip to a list of tuples will allow me to fix this, but I want to retain the zipped object (as it used to be in the good old days of python2.7)

Comment: Well, the second answer to the linked question works in python3.

Comment: 2.7 didn't have a "zip object":  `zip()` returned a list in Python 2.  So if you changed your code to `c = list(zip(a,b))` in Python 3, it would behave exactly as it did in Python 2.

Comment: @anoop There are other answers besides the accepted one that should solve your problem, so I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`zip()` in Python 3 returns an *iterator*; the inputs are zipped as you request elements from it. Iterators are not sortable, no.

You can use the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to 'draw out' the elements and return a sorted list from them:

```
sorted(zip(a, b))
```

You could also convert the `zip()` object to a list by calling `list()` on it, then sort that result in-place with the `list.sort()` method, but that's then more work than just using the `sorted()` function.

`sorted()` takes the same keyword arguments as `list.sort()` does, so you can still use the same `key` function:

Demo:

```
>>> a = [3, 9, 2, 24, 1, 6]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> sorted(zip(a, b))
[(1, 'e'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (9, 'b'), (24, 'd')]
>>> sorted(zip(a, b), key=lambda x: x[1])
[(3, 'a'), (9, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (24, 'd'), (1, 'e')]
```

Also see [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()` ? python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort-python)

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `sort` on zip object, `zip` object doesn't have such attribute. But, you can convert the `zip` object to a list with `list(zipped_object)` and then apply `sort` on it, to do an in-place sort.

But, as zipped object is also an iterable, my recommendation is to use [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions). It will let you write a sort function also, based on which the collection will be sorted.

Here, I am sorting it based on the values of `y` in each `(x,y)` pair. .

```
>>> a = [3,9,2,24,1,6]
>>> b = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> c = zip(a,b)
>>> 
>>> sorted(c, key = lambda x:x[1])
[(3, 'a'), (9, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (24, 'd'), (1, 'e')]
```

Note that, `sorted` will return a new sorted list, whereas `sort` will sort the collection in place.