# Group duplicate rows and Count python (Awkward Structure)

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to work on an analysis of World of Warcraft gear and I'm having an issue with grouping. I can group all unique helms (head-gear) and count them by name. However, in-game your character can wear 2 rings. From the API this comes up as Ring 1 and Ring 2, the order does not matter but I would like to group the combination and count occurences.

### Problem

The 2 same rings on different fingers/slots will appear as 2 separate counts.

```
data = [['Death God\'s Signet', 'Stitchflesh\'s Misplaced Signet', 12],
        ['Stitchflesh\'s Misplaced Signet','Death God\'s Signet', 13],
        ['Sinful Gladiator\'s Ring','Death God\'s Signet', 13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Ring 1', 'Ring 2', 'count'])
```

[image: Results]

### Goal

I want it to be grouped regardless of combination order. Like so,

[image]

### Attempts

I've tried:

- Combining them as a list but it still has the same problem.
- Zipping them and sorting by values (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142227/how-do-i-sort-a-zipped-list-in-python))
- Sorting alphabetically and then grouping/making a list/ zipping
- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort the Ring text with this syntax

```
df['Ring 1'],df['Ring 2']=df[["Ring 1", "Ring 2"]].max(axis=1),df[["Ring 1", "Ring 2"]].min(axis=1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Bit of tweaking and it works the way I needed! Learned something new :)